# How to prevent loading blank page after submitting form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, use-form

I have an issue with reloading a blank page after submitting a contact form. Contact form is working, email is sending to me but after that itself loading a blank page.

I would prefer it to act like this: submiting a form -> sending an message -> clearing values -> without reloading.

So I know about `e.preventDefault()` I tried to use it but for it I need an additional funcion to pass `e` prop. For example:
But I can't pass a hook into the function.

```
  const handleSubmit (e: any) => {
    const [state, handleSubmit] = useForm('xwkjewea');
    e.preventDefault()
    if (state.succeeded) {
      formRef.current.resetFields();
      formRef.current.message.success('Wiadomość została wysłana');
    }
  }
```

I'm using FormSpree to service my message sending and for properly working it I needed to do it like below:

```
const Contact = () => {
  const formRef = useRef<any>();
  const captchaRef = useRef<HCaptcha>(null);

  const [token, setToken] = useState<string>('');
  const [state, handleSubmit] = useForm('formSpree-id');

  if (state.succeeded) {
    formRef.current.resetFields();
    formRef.current.message.success('Sent');
  }

  const onExpire = () => {
    setToken('');
    message.warning('Expired');
  };

  const onError = (err: string) => {
    setToken('');
    message.error(`${err}`);
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Title>Contact</Title>
      <MessageForm
        ref={formRef}
        name='nest-messages'
        onFinish={handleSubmit}
        validateMessages={validateMessages}
      >
    [...]
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *but for it I need an additional funcion to pass e prop*?

Comment: @RubenSmn I had edited post to add example code about that

Comment: can you share code of MessageForm?? how onFinish is called??

Comment: @JatinParmar MessageForm is a form from antd. https://ant.design/components/form

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `e.preventDefault()` in a anonymous function and then pass the `e` event through to the `handleSubmit` function.

```js
<MessageForm
  ref={formRef}
  name="nest-messages"
  onFinish={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleSubmit(e);
  }}
  validateMessages={validateMessages}
>
```

I do recommend put the `state.succeeded` check in a `useEffect` to avoid clearing the form when other states change

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (state.succeeded) {
    formRef.current.resetFields();
    formRef.current.message.success("Sent");
  }
}, [state.succeeded]);
```

Comment: It's seems very nice but after implemanting all of the code nothing happens after submitting form. Only getting error in console that TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function :/